# Aspect around Kotlin suspended function

Tags: kotlin, aop, aspectj, kotlin-coroutines, micrometer

What is the right way to create an aspect around Kotlin suspended function?

From my observation, Micrometer's @Timed aspect does work with them, but shows incorrect result - looks like it measures time between method invocation and suspension, not the full time spent in the method (which should include post-suspension period)

Example of what I'd like to achieve:

```
@CoroutineTimer
suspend fun dbCall() {
    repository.someQuery().awaitFirst() // suspension point
}
```

In this case I'd like to know the full time spent on `dbCall` function, marked with a custom `@CoroutineTimer` annotation. Is there a way do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can measure execution time like this:

```
suspend fun dbCall() {
    val (result, duration) = measureTimedValue {
        repository.someQuery().awaitFirst() // suspension point
    }
    println(duration)
    return result
}
```